# Connecting external rabbitmq client to celery worker in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking, rabbitmq

I have a kubernetes cluster on docker-desktop on which I am running multiple celery workers. I want to connect these celery workers to rabbitmq as the message-broker and redis as the result-backend.

However it is failing with the following error:

```
[2023-06-19 19:41:14,114: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@message-broker:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
```

My method is to run the celery workers as a deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: worker-a
  labels:
  app: worker-a
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
  matchLabels:
    app: worker-a
template:
  metadata:
    name: workera-a
    labels:
      app: worker-a
  spec:
    containers:
      - name: worker
        image: worker:k8s
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: ["celery", ...]
    restartPolicy: Always
```

Then run a selector-less service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: message-broker
spec:
ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5672
    targetPort: 5672
```

And map that to an endpointslice which is the rabbitmq instance running on my localhost where the docker-desktop instance is also running with the k8s cluster:

```
apiVersion: discovery.k8s.io/v1
kind: EndpointSlice
metadata:
  name: message-broker
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/service-name: message-broker
addressType: IPv4
endpoints:
  - addresses:
      - "10.0.0.40"
      - "172.27.208.86"
ports:
  - name: rabbitmq-port
    port: 5672
    protocol: TCP
  - name: rabbitmq-mgmt-port
    port: 15672
    protocol: TCP
```

This is how I've set it up but I'm not sure if this is the best way to map a local service to a kubernetes cluster. And in it's current implementation, the connection is being refused by the celery worker and no connections can be seen on the rabbitmq-management portal.

Comment: Can you run the RabbitMQ broker in Kubernetes, alongside the rest of the infrastructure?  (Remember that the host system, the Docker Desktop VM, and each container is separately "localhost"; saying that RabbitMQ is running "on localhost" is kind of ambiguous.)